# How to disable or only enable certain date ranges

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the external-dragging sample.  I do not want users to be about to drop events outside a specified date range, typically two months before today nor one month after today. Only the current three month window is allowed.  I'd even like those excluded dates to be greyed out.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'll have to hook to the dayRender event to add a class to the cell so you can make it appear some way disabled and then hook the drop event to test if the date dropped is outside of your range and reject it.

Though, I don't know for certain since i haven't used this plugin before, but after a quick glance as the documentation, this is what I would try first.

Comment: Based on similar responses, that is what I tried and so far, it seems to be working.  Not the most glamorous, using an alert, but it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [eventDrop](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/) function.  If the drop occurs outside your date range, revert the drop.